# Solving a question on algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently working on a problem related to algebraic expressions and I am having some trouble with it. The problem is as follows:

For all positive real numbers x and y, which of the following statements is true?

(a) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$;

(b) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$;

(c) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$;

(d) None of the above statements hold generally.

I have attempted to solve this problem, but I'm not entirely confident with my answer. Here's what I have done so far:

For option (a), I have attempted to rationalize the denominator, but I didn't get anything that would help me prove the statement. For option (b), I have squared both sides of the equation and simplified it, but that didn't help either. For option (c), I have tried to simplify the denominator by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}$, but I still couldn't prove the statement.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and I would appreciate any help or advice on how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Let $x=y=1$......

Comment: "I am not sure what I am doing wrong" you knew for sure that two of the three statements were false, but you didn't make any effort to try to demonstrate that any of them were false.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> (d) They almost never hold.

Explanation:

(a) is obviously incorrect, and (c) is also.

(b) holds only for $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$, which is a condition.